# Django filter() query throwing DoesNotExist exception

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to run a `filter()` query by filtering based on a related model and it's throwing a `DoesNotExist` exception.

```
CourseMember.objects.filter(user__last_name__icontains='comadena')
```

I was under the assumption that filtering doesn't throw any DoesNotExist exceptions, but simply returns an empty queryset if no matches are left.  Is there some other `get()` going on since I'm technically querying a related table for the filter?

Also, strangely enough, the error only gets thrown for this specific `user__last_name__icontains` search value. It works with other values like `'smith'`, `'johnson'`, `'frink'`, etc.

Models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
  email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True, max_length=254)
  first_name = models.TextField(blank=True) 
  last_name = models.TextField(blank=True)
  is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Course(models.Model):
  coursenum = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
  title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  school = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  category = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class CourseMember(models.Model):
  create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
  course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  role = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True) 
  section = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
```

Here's the error report when I run the query in the terminal:

```
CourseMember.objects.filter(user__last_name__icontains='comadena')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 119, in __repr__
    return repr(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 459, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
  File "/home/bookeducator/go/course/models.py", line 236, in __str__
    return 'CourseMember: %s (%s)' % (self.user.email, self.role)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 572, in __get__
    rel_obj = qs.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 357, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name)
account.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Could you provide your relevant model definitions and the complete traceback you are getting? Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully the edit helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue.  The error info pointed out that the error is cause when the **str** method is called and I found a certain object in my database that was causing the error.  My system is set up to filter out all objects who do not have `my_instance.is_active = True`.  This was causing a problem, because the filter wasn't allowing us to return the attached user object that is no longer active.